# What is the difference between onBackPressed and onCancel in DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment, onbackpressed

When trying to use the back button of a `dialog fragment`

I'm curious as to the difference between using `onBackPressed()` (or `onBackPressedCallBack`) and `onCancel()`.

I tried to define the data forwarding event of the `back key` using `onBackPressedCallback()` and `OnBackPressedDispatcher()` in the `dialog fragment`, but it didn't work.

In the end, I passed the data using `onCancel()`.

Why doesn't the back key with `onBackPressed()` work?

***UPDATED***

```
public class WritingCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    OnBackPressedCallback callback;
    
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return view;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        callback =  new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
            @Override
            public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onBackPressed()` of the dialog itself intercepts the back button press before the host Activity ever gets a shot at it. The default behavior is to call `cancel()` on the dialog and not pass it on to the Activity. That's why adding your callback to the Activity isn't doing anything. If you want to specifically handle the back button press, you would need to subclass Dialog to override it and use that class as the Dialog you create in `onCreateDialog()`. Something like this:

```java
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(requireContext(), getTheme()) {
            @Override
            public void onBackPressed() {
                MyDialogFragment.this.onBackPressed();
                // And maybe you also want to call cancel() here.
            }
        };
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }

    private void onBackPressed() {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

A dialog is canceled not only when back is pressed, but also if the user taps outside the dialog or presses the cancel button (if you added one to the dialog), or if you manually call `cancel()` on it or its host DialogFragment. So performing your action in `onCancel()` covers more events than just the back button being pressed.

A third possible event you can hook onto (with an OnDismissListener) is the dialog being dismissed, which is any time it is closed, including when it is canceled or when the screen rotates.

Comment: I'm not good at English, so some parts of your answer are a little difficult to understand.

`1.` I didn't quite understand the meaning of  `onBackPressed() of the dialog itself intercepts the back button press before the host Activity ever gets a shot at it.` Can you explain a little more clearly?

`2.` In `not pass it on to the Activity.`,
What do you mean you don't pass?

`3.` In `adding your callback to the Activity`, do you mean the code in `onAttach()`?

thank you and sorry...

Comment: 1. When the back button is pressed, the OS calls `dialog.onBackPressed()`, not `activity.onBackPressed()`. So you cannot change the behavior of the back button in a dialog by using the Activity. You can only do it by subclassing Dialog and overriding `Dialog.onBackPressed()`.

Comment: 2. If you look at the source code of  `Dialog.onBackPressed()`, you will see that it calls `dialog.cancel()` and does not do anything to the Activity, which is why `Activity.onBackPressed()` is never called if you press the back button while a dialog is open. By "not passing" I mean it does not pass along the message to the Activity that the back button was pressed.

Comment: 3. Yes, I am referring to the OnBackPressedCallback you created in `onAttach()` and gave to your Activity using `getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback()`. You are telling the Activity what you want it to do when its `onBackPressed` function is called, but that function won't be called if a Dialog is on screen.

Comment: In answer `1`, you said that you have to `subclass dialog` and `override Backpressed()`. But what about in `DialogFragment`? `onBackPressed()` is not visible in `DialogFragment`.

Regarding answer `3`, then the reason the `BackPressed` event I defined in the code didn't work is that, in `onAttach()`, a callback was sent to the `activity`, and it should work in `activity.onBackPressed()`, but the actual action is `Dialog. onBackPressed()`, so nothing happened?

Comment: There is no `DialogFragment.onBackPressed()` available to override. You can return an instance of your Dialog subclass in `DialogFragment.onCreateDialog()`. I added an example of how to do that. And, yes, to your last question.

Comment: I think I finally understand to some extent.

Thank you so much for your kind and detailed reply.